# What does the phrase "to within" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases, mathematics

While I was reading the book ['Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS'](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms), I came across the sentence:

> ...is equal to g(n) to within a constant factor.

I've seen something about it in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20within), but 'to within' is not clear to me, as I am not a native English speaker. 
Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Math question, not English language.  Also this post is replete with typos, which makes it hard to tell what the question really is.

Comment: @xanne what does merriam webster telling about it?

Comment: Well, Norman, what do you think it means?  Why doesn't MW answer your question?

Comment: •drove to within 50 yards of the green -- M-W example about golf.  That means the golf ball landed less than 50 yards from the green. •worked hard to within five minutes of closing time -- M-W example.  means that if closing time was 5:00 pm, he worked hard until 4:55 pm or a bit later.

Comment: To within means something is measured as being close to an end. Your example says that variance is a (probably small) constant.

Comment: Wrong forum for this but Ill help. That section of the book is talking about growth order. In Big O notation we drop the leading coefficients + constants (they are insignificant for growth functions). Big O, Theta and Omega are just generalizations of how  an algorithm will perform (within upper & lower bounds). So an algorithm that is ax2+bn+c is O(n2) for example. It means that the upper bound of the algorithm is no worse than n squared for some constant input factor "n". The algorithm will never perform worse than n squared for some value of n.  Check ELL site. Talk to your prof.

Comment: see also https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D1%81+%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E+%D0%B4%D0%BE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a non-math illustration will help clarify the meaning of "to within."

"The bullet penetrated his abdomen ***to within*** 1 cm of his spine." It describes that the bullet penetrated the abdomen and came to rest 1 cm or less distance from the spine.

"The home-made rocket climbed ***to within*** 5 miles of the stratosphere." This means the rocket climbed from the surface of the earth up to an altitude that is 5 miles from the stratosphere, up to but not including the stratosphere. So we don't know exactly how high the rocket went but its somewhere "within" that range.

Answer (score 4):

**A is B to within a constant factor**

means

**A is between (B times a constant) and (B times a constant)** where the first constant and the second constant are not necessarily the same.

---

Context:

From page 45 of the third edition (Cormen, Thomas H., et al. Introduction to Algorithms, MIT Press, 2014--via ProQuest Ebook Central):

> [image: Figure 3.1(a) from page 45 of Cormen, Thomas H., et al. Introduction to Algorithms, MIT Press, 2014]
>
> Figure 3.1(a) gives an intuitive picture of functions *f(n)* and *g(n)*, where
>   *f(n) = Θ(g(n))*. For all values of *n* at and to the right of *n<sub>0</sub>*, the value of *f(n)*
>   lies at or above *c<sub>1</sub>g(n)* and at or below *c<sub>2</sub>g(n)*. In other words, for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*, the function *f(n)* is
>   equal to *g(n)* to within a constant factor.

The key is in

> the value of *f(n)*
>   lies at or above *c<sub>1</sub>g(n)* and at or below *c<sub>2</sub>g(n)*

where *c<sub>1</sub>* and  *c<sub>2</sub>* are defined by the caption of Figure 3.1 as being positive constants.

So we can rephrase as

the value of *f(n)* **is greater than or equal to** a constant value times *g(n)* **and less than or equal to** a constant value times *g(n)*.

Answer (score 3):

Within refers to a margin of error. It is equal to g(n) plus or minus some constant factor. In math terms, g(n) = x +/- constant factor.

Comment: I would suggest correcting all three of these sentences. It's not a margin of error but a set of bounds; it's not addition but multiplication (note the term *factor*); it's the value of something else that's being expressed in terms of a constant factor of *g(n)*, not *g(n)* that's having its own value affected.